# Not getting all the column in a single line, one column displaying down even though I have space

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

[image: This is how my ugly table looks]

I want the "dept_no" column to be displayed next to the "comm" column in a single line.
why it showing the column name again after the 3rd row entry?

I want a clean table with all the column to be displayed in a line with data entry down without the repeat of the column as seen in the image

Comment: Are you sure that you are using sql-server and not Oracle?

Comment: Why have you tagged pl\sql and SQL server? SQL Server uses T-SQL, Oracle uses PL\SQL. That *looks* like sqlcmd, and therefore the reason there's a new line is because you go to the line character limit. Why are you trying to use SQLCMS as a GUI at all? It's a CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding table contents, we're talking about Oracle and SQL*Plus command line tool and Scott's sample schema (its EMP table).

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> set linesize 80
SQL>
SQL> select * From emp where rownum < 5;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800
        20

      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300
        30

      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500
        30


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975
        20


SQL>
```

Apparently, all those columns can't fit (default) 80 characters line width, so - enlarge it:

```
SQL> set linesize 100
SQL>
SQL> select * From emp where rownum < 5;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975                    20

SQL>
```

Maybe you'll have to adjust Command Prompt window's properties (width of "Screen buffer size" and "Window size"), i.e. enlarge them as well.

---

Finally, note the way you (and me) have the "original" query results displayed: see how column headers repeat? That's because `pagesize` is too low. Reverting linesize back to 80, but applying `set pagesize` command:

```
SQL> set linesize 80
SQL> set pagesize 100
SQL>
SQL> select * From emp where rownum < 5;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800
        20

      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300
        30

      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500
        30

      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975
        20


SQL>
```

See? No more headers are repeated (would be, if the result spans more than 100 lines).

---

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG060)'s a list of all SQL*Plus `set` commands; have a look for more information.

Comment: littlefoot, How do you know this much about Oracle?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation @Littlefoot. I set the linesize to 90 and it worked. At linesize 80 it was same as earlier

Comment: You're welcome. I know that 80 is as it was before; that's what I said. Me, reverting it to 80, was to show what PAGESIZE does.